# iOS display data from array in table, except for last index

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray, directions

I have displayed my data in a tableview from an array, but I do not want to display the last object in the array. How do I accomplish this? Thanks

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    MQManeuver *manuever = [[route maneuvers] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.imageView.image = nil;

    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    cell.detailTextLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = manuever.narrative;
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    float distance = manuever.distance;
    NSString *distance1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", distance];
    cell.textLabel.text = [distance1 stringByAppendingFormat:@" miles"];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: in numberOfRowsInSection, just return `[[route maneuvers] count] - 1;`

Comment: Another option is to remove the object from array.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use this one... I think this will work fine .

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if([[route maneuvers] count] == 0)
        return 0;
    else
       return [[route maneuvers] count] - 1;
}
```

Comment: This is a little dangerous because you can return an NSInteger. If count is 0, then you return -1. That's not a valid return value for this method (should be >= 0... or rather, the return type SHOULD be NSUInteger).

Comment: Yes boss Thanks for it.I think its human scence.So he can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Shift NSArray  data to NSMutableArray

```
NSMutableArray Methods for Removing Objects:
– removeAllObjects
– removeLastObject   ///you can use removeLastObject Method
– removeObject:
– removeObject:inRange:
– removeObjectAtIndex:
– removeObjectsAtIndexes:
– removeObjectIdenticalTo:
– removeObjectIdenticalTo:inRange:
– removeObjectsFromIndices:numIndices:
– removeObjectsInArray:
– removeObjectsInRange:
```